# how can i display only groups list from facebook using android sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

please any one guide me how to  display only groups list from  Facebook account using Facebook sdk. I have search for that particular topic i found some link `"https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer"`
i am logged in that link i am seeing only my groups details using

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/100000923820661/groups"
```

but my doubt is how to display that groups list in my android emulator.

```
Thanks in Advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you showed above is a Graph API request. You can make these requests using the Android SDK, as shown here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/. You will receive JSON as the return value, and you can use this however you see fit in your Android application.

Comment: try{
                    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("fields", "name");
                    Log.v("info", mFacebook.request("me/groups"));
                              
                  mAsyncRunner.request("me/groups", bundle, new FriendListRequestListener());
                  }catch(Exception e){
                      e.getMessage();
                  }
i have used this code i got empty response can u please tell me where i was doing wrong

Comment: I can't tell from this code in isolation what you may be doing wrong. Take a look at the link provided and see if that approach works better. Also, make sure that you're correctly authenticated at the time of making the call, and try using the Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) so you know what kind of data to expect in the response.